# Plots.jl GKS: can't connect to GKS socket application on Windows

Tags: julia, gr

Trying to use Plots package, but getting following issue;

```
julia> using Plots
julia> gr()
Plots.GRBackend()
julia> Plots.plot(rand(5), rand(5))
connect: No error
GKS: can't connect to GKS socket application
GKS: Open failed in routine OPEN_WS
GKS: GKS not in proper state. GKS must be either in the state WSOP or WSAC in routine ACTIVATE_WS
GKS: GKS not in proper state. GKS must be either in the state WSAC or SGOP in routine FILLAREA
GKS: GKS not in proper state. GKS must be either in the state WSAC or SGOP in routine FILLAREA
GKS: GKS not in proper state. GKS must be either in the state WSAC or SGOP in routine POLYLINE
```

Tried removing, updatign packages via `]` , and downloaded required dependencies, but can't plot any graphs due to error. Following is package info;

```
-- Gnuplot (installed): C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin
-- GR (unzip) : C:\Users\John\Downloads\gr-latest-Windows-x86_64.tar\gr-latest-Windows-x86_64\gr\bin\

(@v1.9) pkg> status
Status `C:\Users\John\.julia\environments\v1.9\Project.toml`
  [28b8d3ca] GR v0.72.9
  [4b11ee91] Gaston v1.1.0
  [dc211083] Gnuplot v1.4.1
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.38.17
```

After making some changes in ENV variables, getting;

```
julia> Plots.plot(rand(5), rand(5))
Error showing value of type Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}:
ERROR: could not load library "C:\Users\John\Downloads\gr-latest-Windows-x86_64.tar\gr-latest-Windows-x86_64\gr\bin\bin\libGR"
The specified module could not be found.
Stacktrace:
  [1] dlopen(s::String, flags::UInt32; throw_error::Bool)
    @ Base.Libc.Libdl .\libdl.jl:117
```

Comment: Issue resolved after A) Correcting path of GRDIR (env variable). by removing extran \bin B) Main issue was Antivirus deleting gksqt.exe, disabling AV made plotting successful.